# when inputting into a struct with std::cin it bugs out

Tags: c++

i wanted to make a code that calculated the triangles area with triangles points coordinates

when user inputs a number for example 1 it writes -1.5458e+037

i have tried some little tweaks like using `std::` but didnt work at all

tbh im new to c++ so i might not get some things and i request to thoroughly explain somethings

````
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
//#define str string
//using namespace std

int inputStarted=1;//being used in inputCo function

struct cords{
    float x;
    float y;
};

float distance(cords a,cords b){
    float distanceX;
    float distanceY;
    distanceX= (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x);
    distanceY= (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y);
    return sqrt(distanceX+distanceY);
}
void area(cords A, cords B, cords C){
    float ab =distance(A,B); 
    float ac =distance(A,C);
    float bc =distance(B,C);
    float S=(ab+ac+bc)/2;
    float Area=sqrt(S*(S-ab)*(S-ac)*(S-bc));
    std::cout<<Area;
}
void printCords(cords a){
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"x - "<<a.x<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"y - "<<a.y<<std::endl<<std::endl;
}
void inputCo(cords a){
    if(inputStarted==1){
        std::cout<<"input your 1-st point's X position/coordinate  -  ";// = 1
        std::cin>>a.x;
        std::cout<<"input your 1-st point's Y position/coordinate  -  ";// = 4
        std::cin>>a.y;
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    if(inputStarted==2){
        std::cout<<"input your 2-nd point's X position/coordinate  -  ";// = 5
        std::cin>>a.x;
        std::cout<<"input your 2-nd point's Y position/coordinate  -  ";// = 8
        std::cin>>a.y;
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    if(inputStarted==3){
        std::cout<<"input your 3-rd point's X position/coordinate  -  ";// = 3
        std::cin>>a.x;
        std::cout<<"input your 3-rd point's Y position/coordinate  -  ";// = 6
        std::cin>>a.y;
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    inputStarted++;
}
int main(){
    cords A;
    cords B;
    cords C;
    inputCo(A);
    inputCo(B);
    inputCo(C);
    printCords(A);
    printCords(B);
    printCords(C);
    area(A,B,C);    
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

```
void inputCo(cords a){
```

You are passing arguments by copy, so only the copied value is modified. To modify the original value, pass by reference instead:

```
void inputCo(cords& a){
```

Other functions do not modify the parameter, so there you may pass by copy.

Comment: what do you mean by copy?

Comment: @NkaLutidze Your function parameter is copied into local variable named `a` when the function is called. You modify this local variable, not the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a copy of coord into the input function that gets modified and when the function exits, the copy is no longer the one you are using.

you need to either pass in a pointer or a reference to the coord so that it can be modified without making a copy

Something like changing the input function to:

```
void inputCo(cords &a)
```